# Is there a Unicode string which gets longer when converted to lowercase?

Tags: string, unicode

The string `'ß'` gets longer (as measured in Unicode codepoints) when converted to uppercase (it becomes `'SS'`).

Is there a similar string that gets longer when converted to lowercase?

Comment: There isn't a [Unicode normalization form](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) that will also covert such eszett to 'ss' under lowercase as well? (The 'SS' comes through some normalization; so which one and why? I imagine it depends on context..)

Comment: user2864740, I leave it up to an answerer to decide whether application of a given normalization form is suited for an answer to this question.

Comment: See `F` in http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/CaseFolding.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, this Java finds when the uppercase version is longer than the original

```
for (char chr = 0; chr < Character.MAX_VALUE; chr++) {
    String str = String.valueOf(chr);
    String upper = str.toUpperCase();
    if (upper.length() > 1) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s => %s (%d)", str,
                Arrays.toString(upper.toCharArray()), upper.length()));
    }
}
```

Which outputs things like your original example

```
ß => [S, S] (2)
ŉ => [ʼ, N] (2)
ǰ => [J, ̌] (2)
ΐ => [Ι, ̈, ́] (3)
```

If I change this to toLowerCase() there is only one result

```
İ => [i, ̇] (2)
```

Comment: Verified this with a similar throwaway program in Python.

Comment: Did anyone really understand the question? The answers are simply not helpful, as it's for upper not lower

Answer (score 2):

http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt

There are some characters in here that have to be handled with multiple bytes. These mostly seem to involve the dotage of the letters I and J.